# Root path works for all HTTP methods

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application.yml where context path is mentioned as below.

```
server:
  servlet:
    contextPath: /home
```

I have the following RootController.java

```
@RestController
@Slf4j
@RequestMapping("/")
public class RootController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public String getContent() throws IOException {
       return "This is root content";
    }

}
```

But the root endpoint works for all HTTP methods like 'POST', 'PUT', etc., even though method is mentioned as 'GET' in @RequestMapping. It is supposed to work only for GET method. I'm not sure about the problem. Can someone help fix this ?

Comment: Looks fine to me. What Spring version do you use? You may use ```@GetMapping``` instead of ```@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)``` (since 4.3)

Comment: I think it would be useful to also see a sample curl request/response.

Comment: @Peteef  Tried that. It doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have a post mapping method?

Comment: @ShiheZhang No I don't have a post mapping method.

Comment: Apply mapping in handler methods

Comment: Would that possible some default setting map that path to all method?